# Why does `public void append(LogEvent ev) have ev.getContextData().size() == 0`? (otherwise ev is fine)

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

`logEvent.getContextData().size() == 0` and `logEvent.getContextStack().size() == 0` but otherwise the attributes of the `LogEvent` are fine in:

```
public class MyAppender extends AbstractAppender {
    .........
    @override
    public void append(LogEvent ev) {
        ev.getDataContext().size(); // <=== how can this equals 0?
        ev.getStackContext().size(); // <=== how can this equals 0?
        ....
    }
}
```

I cannot figure-out why this is the case. Do I need to create an `AbstractConverter`? `AbstractFilter`? Is my `log4j2.xml` or maybe the plugin config wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "equals 0"? Neither of these methods return a number type. Do you mean that their size is zero? What do you _expect_ them to contain?

Comment: @user31601 yes. the size() is zero. empty. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: So what do you expected it to be? My understanding is that both the MDC and the NDC require you to put something on them before they contain anything.

Comment: @user31601 I need to know the canonical class name of the object that created that LogEvent, as well as the method name where it was created. how do I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, it looks like what you're actually after is the [location information](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation). In a custom appender, this can be obtained by walking the stack trace provided by `LogEvent.getSource()`. You should be aware that obtaining this information is *expensive* though (see the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation)).

**Edit**

As you've stated, location information can be very useful, so it's a shame that it's expensive to obtain. Unfortunately, there's nothing Log4J can do about that - it's down to java's architecture.

One cheaper method that's commonly used to obtain the class name at least, is to ensure that the `Logger` being logged to is named after the class in which it's used (see [documentation here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html#Logger_Names)). Then, you can obtain the class name in an appender by calling `LogEvent.getLoggerName()`. Note, however, that if you're writing a general `Appender` implementation that may be reused across several projects, it would be bad practice to *assume* that this would always be the calling class's  name. Instead, it should be interpreted as "the functional context that the logging call came from, as determined by the application".

Comment: Those links do not work, but I've found the docs. Yet, the name of the class and method that invoked the logging method are such a basic thing you'd want to know.

Comment: I've corrected the links (they're both to the same location) - sorry for that

Comment: I agree, this information us _useful_, which is why Log4J provides you with a means to obtain it. However, the architecture of _java itself_ makes it expensive to obtain (although in other languages, it may well be impossible).

Comment: Wow. I just wasted 4 hours of my life. I greatly, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - glad to help :)